How to call a stored procedure (Oracle SQL) with variables filtered in a dashboard in PowerBI
(Edit: I rewrote my question and hope that it become clear what I want to do this in PowerBI)
I'm new to PowerBI and I would like to use it as visualization for my stored procedures which are in an Oracle database.
At first I run a procedure where I fetch all needed data for the analysis. This result table is about 30 gb which run on a weekly basis due to runtime. From there i use a second procedure with a bunch of subselects where I put in the data of interest (Customer, Production plant etc.) in the core query and get a lean result only for these variables and for this I use a tool written in java and visualize the result as a Sankey Chart.
So what I want to do in PowerBI: create a dashboard with a sankey chart, and the user get a result by filtering the mentioned variables. So what PowerBI needs to do is to pass a call to run the procedure with the filtered variables and fetch the result.
I understand that I can call a procedure and pass the variables when I establish the connection (direct query and put in the statement). But is it possible to do this out of a dashboard by setting a filter?
